# Removing the selected options to other option

Tags: laravel

The problem is before adding a new container, after I added the max number of stock-details-container and I remove one of it then I changed the selected value of the other containers. When I add a new container, the new added container disabled the previously selected item in the other containers even if it is not their selected values anymore.

```
<div class="d-flex gap-3 flex-column" id="stock-details-container">
                <div class="d-flex gap-3 justify-content-center align-items-center stock-details">
                    <select name="stocksname" class="form-control stocks-select">
                        <option value="">Choose item</option>
                        @foreach($stocks as $stock)
                            <option value="{{$stock->name}}">{{$stock->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <button class="btn btn-close remove-stock"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex gap-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add-more">Add more</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Complete</button>
            </div>

<script>
```

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

```
var selectedOptions = [];

// For adding a new contianer
document.getElementById("add-more").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var container = document.getElementById("stock-details-container");
    var stocksSelect = document.querySelector(".stocks-select");
    var stocksOptions = stocksSelect.options;
    
    if (container.children.length < stocksOptions.length) {
        if (container.children.length === 0) {
            container.appendChild(createStockDetailsElement(true));
        } else {
            var clone = container.firstElementChild.cloneNode(true);
            var selectedValue = clone.querySelector(".stocks-select").value;
            clone.querySelector(".stocks-select").innerHTML = '';
            
            for (var i = 0; i < stocksOptions.length; i++) {
                var clonedOption = document.createElement("option");
                clonedOption.value = stocksOptions[i].value;
                clonedOption.text = stocksOptions[i].text;
                if (selectedOptions.includes(clonedOption.value)) {
                    clonedOption.disabled = true;
                }
                clone.querySelector(".stocks-select").appendChild(clonedOption);
            }
            container.appendChild(clone);
        }
    } else {
        alert("No more items available to add.");
    }
});

//For removeing a container
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("remove-stock")) {
        var select = event.target.parentNode.querySelector(".stocks-select");
        var removedOption = document.createElement("option");
        removedOption.value = select.value;
        removedOption.text = select.value;
        select.appendChild(removedOption); 
        
        // Remove the option from selectedOptions array
        var index = selectedOptions.indexOf(select.value);
        if (index !== -1) {
            selectedOptions.splice(index, 1);
        }
        
        event.target.closest(".stock-details").remove(); // Remove the stock details
    }
});

// Event listener to track selected options
document.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("stocks-select")) {
        var selectedOption = event.target.value;
        // Add selected option to selectedOptions array
        if (!selectedOptions.includes(selectedOption)) {
            selectedOptions.push(selectedOption);
        }
        // Disable selected option in other containers
        var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".stocks-select");
        containers.forEach(function(container) {
            var options = container.options;
            for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].value === selectedOption) {
                    options[i].disabled = true;
                } else {
                    options[i].disabled = false; // Enable other options
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

function createStockDetailsElement(includeChooseItemOption) {
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.classList.add("d-flex", "gap-3", "justify-content-center", "align-items-center", "stock-details");

    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.name = "stocksname";
    select.classList.add("form-control", "stocks-select");

    if (includeChooseItemOption) {
        var chooseItemOption = document.createElement("option");
        chooseItemOption.value = "";
        chooseItemOption.text = "Choose item";
        select.appendChild(chooseItemOption);
    }

    // Add options from the original select, disabling selected options
    var stocksOptions = document.querySelector(".stocks-select").options;
    for (var i = 0; i < stocksOptions.length; i++) {
        var clonedOption = document.createElement("option");
        clonedOption.value = stocksOptions[i].value;
        clonedOption.text = stocksOptions[i].text;
        if (selectedOptions.includes(clonedOption.value)) {
            clonedOption.disabled = true;
        }
        select.appendChild(clonedOption);
    }

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.classList.add("form-control");

    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.classList.add("btn", "btn-close", "remove-stock");

    container.appendChild(select);
    container.appendChild(input);
    container.appendChild(button);

    return container;
}
```

});